# Differences between images - byte array file to Mat vs Bitmap

Tags: android, arrays, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

[byte array image file to Mat vs byte array image file to Bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN7hK.jpg)

We working with `opencv` on `Android Studio`.
We convert byte array to `Mat` and save it back to disk. Also convert the byte array to Bitmap and save it. After comparing between them we got following differences. any explanation? attached photos from beyond compare

**Mat code:**

```
Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bytes), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

**Bitmap code:**

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, bitmapOptions);
```

Comment: Since there's a lot missing, I'll have to guess -- you're probably comparing BGR with RGB.

Comment: what exactly is missing? 
I have tried to convert BGR2RGB and vice versa by opencv (Imgproc.cvtColor) and problem still exists. it seems there is no way to understand image color-space with opencv api. any ideas?